# Debugging Alamofire request

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to debug the HTTP header & body that's sent to a server endpoint by Alamofire. All the header parameters seem to be correct as I get an acknowledgement from the endpoint I'm dealing with, however, I'm having trouble with the server, the JSON I'm sending to it in the parameters field isn't being parsed. How can I find out what's being sent in the request?

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                    "API-Key": apiKey,
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                ]

let data = ["name":"Don Jonhson"]


Alamofire.request(endPointUrl, method: .post,  parameters: data, 
encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON() { 
           response in

           if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
              switch(status){
               case 201:
                debugPrint(response)
               default:
                debugPrint(response)
              }
           }

          ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a simple string dictionary you have to use alamofire's parameters instead

```
let params: Parameters = ["name":"Don Jonhson"]

Alamofire.request(endPointUrl, method: .post,  parameters: params, 
encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON() { 
       response in

       if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
          switch(status){
           case 201:
            debugPrint(response)
           default:
            debugPrint(response)
          }
       }

      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

How can I check the name has been inserted correctly in the the http body as JSON?

Comment: When you receives a response you can check if it's 200 so you receive back some data with it otherwise you can check your backend to see if the user you sent them has been created or not. you have tried my answer if it has worked can you please mark it as correct answer?

Comment: I have been getting a 200 response already. The problem is that I get an error from the server to say the JSON in the body of the request is incorrect. This is what I want to debug.

The server endpoint is interpreting the header information correctly i.e. the API-Key, the content type and so on. The server should also parse the http body which contains some JSON data. The server endpoint complains about the JSON that's sent. 

So what I'm trying to figure out is when the request leaves the iPhone what's actually in the http body & how can I get that information from Alamofire?